# Finding installed packages not supported by the Ubuntu team

Tags: apt, package-management

How can I check whether I installed any Universe or Multiverse packages which are, according to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, "ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu team" ?
What I'm looking for is a command line for Ubuntu 18 LTS server (no GUI) to list installed packages by componenent, including installed packages that are not available from `apt-get` (not part of the archives configured in `/etc/apt/sources.list`).
`aptitude versions '?name(.)'` lists the available packages and their installation status, but does not output their source component, nor does `apt-cache`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `ubuntu-support-status` command

> ```
> $ ubuntu-support-status --help
> Usage: ubuntu-support-status [options]
>
> Options:
>   -h, --help          show this help message and exit
>   --show-unsupported  Show unsupported packages on this machine
>   --show-supported    Show supported packages on this machine
>   --show-all          Show all packages with their status
>   --list              Show all packages in a list
> ```

with corresponding argument `--show-unsupported`.

Below is example from my 16.04.5 LTS system:

> ```
> $ ubuntu-support-status --show-unsupported
>
> Support status summary of 'hostname':
>
> You have 94 packages (1.9%) supported until April 2021 (Community - 5y)
> You have 2668 packages (54.0%) supported until April 2021 (Canonical - 5y)
> You have 647 packages (13.1%) supported until April 2019 (Community - 3y)
>
> You have 79 packages (1.6%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
> You have 1456 packages (29.4%) that are unsupported
>
> No longer downloadable:
> acroread acroread-bin:i386 cpp-4.4 cpp-4.5 cpp-4.6 
> ... 
>
> Unsupported: 
> abiword-plugin-grammar adequate aglfn alien android android-tools-adb 
> android-tools-fastboot ant ant-optional antiword apt-file
> ...
> y-ppa-manager yad zenmap
> ```

(I added the `...` to limit number of lines).

Comment: If you want you could also mention `vrms` to list "non-free" software.

Comment: See my answer below for what I finally did to get a readable list of everything that is not fully supported and without the clutter.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Open Synaptic Package Manager. Go to "Origin" (bottom left).

Comment: This is not a command line tool. GUI is unavailable on my server.

Answer (score 0):

[The Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq#What_is_the_difference_between_a_native_Debian_package_and_a_non-native_package.3F) shows how you can tell the difference between native and non-native packages.

If you want to see the relation between `sources.list` and installed packages, you can use `dpkg --get-selections` and `apt-cache show` and `apt-get update`.

Or search in a database of packages with curl.

In Fedora/RHEL there's a tool for verifying that files come from supported packages.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` does not output any sections. `apt-cache show \*` does but is much slower than accepted solution because it gives much more info.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did to get a readable list of everything that is not fully supported and without the clutter:

```
# sed removes summary lines and packages supported for five years
# and prints one line per not fully supported package:
ubuntu-support-status --show-all | sed '0,/summary/ d; /^Support.*5y/,/^$/ d; /^You have/,/^$/ d; /:/ n; s- $--; s- -\n-g'

No longer downloadable:


Unsupported:
cgroup-tools
...

Supported until April 2021 (Community - 3y):
fonts-dejavu
libx86-1
openjdk-8-jre
openjdk-8-jre-headless
```